# SQLAlchemy: filter many-to-one relationship where the one object has a list containing a specific value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have some tables like this:

```
class Genre(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'))

class Song(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    artist = db.relationship('Artist', uselist=False)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'))

class Artist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    genres = db.relationship('Genre')
    songs = db.relationship('Song')
```

So basically, Songs have one Artist. And each Artist can have multiple Genres.

I am trying to get all Songs by any Artist whose list of Genre's contains a Genre by a specific name. I did some researching, and I found something very close:

```
Song.query.filter(Artist.genres.any(Genre.name.in_([genre_name_im_looking_for])))
```

This will sort of work, but not for all cases. For example, the above statement will also return all Songs with Artists who have the Genre 'indie rock'. How can I specify that I don't want the Genre name to be in a list of values, but to be a specific value?

```
Song.query.filter(Artist.genres.any(Genre.name='rock'))
```

is also not possible because it is a keyword expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Song.query.filter(Artist.genres.any(Genre.name == 'rock'))`? (comparison rather than assignment)

Comment: @Wash is right, but even `in_(['rock'])` should not really match `indie rock`. Maybe your `Artist` has both `rock` and `indie rock` genres.

Comment: @van yeah, I don't think it should match either. I checked my database... the Artist did not have rock, but a lot of genres with 'rock' in the name, like 'indie rock'. Still confused why it's matching.

Comment: @Wash thanks, I'll try that later. Usually you can use an expression, like Artist.query.filter_by(name='whatever'), so I didn't even think about using a comparison. Still new to this sqlalchemy business.

Comment: @van, I tried your query, but I am still getting Artists that have 'indie rock', but not 'rock' in their list of genres. And I have checked that the Artist doesn't have both genres.

Comment: @van, I did a little more debugging. It turns out that `Song.query.filter(Artist.genres.any(Genre.name == 'rock'))` is returning all the songs in my database. (I hadn't noticed this before because well... I mostly listen to songs that are of the rock genre.. so I added an Artist that doesn't have any affiliation with the rock genre.

Comment: @van `Artist.query.filter(Artist.genres.any(Genre.name.like('rock'))).all()` will get me all the artists who only have the 'rock ' genre. Now I just need to preface that query with a Song query somehow so I can get all the songs from those artists...

Comment: OK, I completely missed that part of your query where you do not have link between `Song` and `Artist` resulting in a cartesian product. See my answer with the sample data for one liner.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With this test data:

```
# Test Data
artists = [
    Artist(
        name='should match rock',
        genres=[Genre(name='rock'), Genre(name='pop')],
        songs=[Song(name='love'), Song(name='hate')]
    ),
    Artist(
        name='should NOT match',
        genres=[Genre(name='indie rock')],
        songs=[Song(name='elsewhere')]
    ),
]

db.session.add_all(artists)
db.session.commit()
```

Query below should do what you want:

```
q = Song.query.filter(Song.artist.has(Artist.genres.any(Genre.name == 'rock')))
assert len(q.all()) == 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Quick question for you, I also have another table, Users, which has a one to many relationship with songs, and I'm now looking to augment your suggested query to filter the songs that belong to a specific user.  This query works `Song.query.filter(Song.artist.has(
            Artist.genres.any(Genre.name == 'genre'))).filter(
            Song.user == some_user_object).all()` What kind of effect would swapping the filter statements have on performance?

Comment: I do not think that there would be any performance difference in any modern RDBMS.

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, I found out one way to approach this problem, although a bit differently than what I wanted.

First, to get all the Artists that contain a specific Genre, I executed:

```
artists = Artist.query.filter(
    Artist.genres.any(Genre.name.like('genre_name'))).all()
```

Then, I iterated through each Artist, and queried the Song model by using the artist as a keyword expression in the filter, like so:

```
for a in artist:
    most_common_genre_songs = Song.query.filter_by(artist=a).all()
```

I am not sure if there is a more efficient way to make this call, or do it in a one-liner (I'm betting there is), but for now, this will do.