# SQLAlchemy: Query Parent with Efficient Child Search & Filter

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've seen a few topics that are similar, but can't seem to get any of them to work efficiently.

E.g.: [SQLAlchemy: filter many-to-one relationship where the one object has a list containing a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804756/sqlalchemy-filter-many-to-one-relationship-where-the-one-object-has-a-list-cont])

I have a DB structure like so:

```
class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Items(Base):
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))

class Criteria(Base):  
    _name = db.Column('name', db.String(250), nullable=False, unique=False)

class Response(Base):
    item_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('items.id'))
    criterion_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('criteria.id'))
    value = db.Column('value', db.Text(), nullable=True)
    item = db.relationship('Items', backref=db.backref('responses', lazy='joined', cascade='all, delete'))
```

I'm trying to filter `Items` by a series of `Response` values like so:

```
filters = [{'c_id':5, 'value': 'yes'}, {'c_id':6, 'value': 'no'}]

items = Items.query
for f in filters:
    items = items.filter(Item.responses.any(and_(Response.value == f['value'], Response.criterion_id == f['c_id'])))
```

The query succeeds and I get my `Items` but the query is very slow on datasets as small as 100 `Items` with less than 2,000 combined `Responses`.

I'm paginating the results so only 25 results are returned to the user max.

My questions is there a more efficient way to return these results using `join()`?

Python 3.6, Flask-sqlalchemy, MySQL